# Running a tensorflow program multiple times each time afresh

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following tensorflow code in a script named `fit.py`to fit to a given data. I reuse the variables `w` and `b` for the whole sequence length.

```
seq_len=10

x_data=np.random.uniform(0,1,(10,1))
y_data=x_data*0.8 + 0.5

x=tf.placeholer('float',[seq_len,1])
y=tf.placeholer('float',[seq_len,1])


with tf.variable_scope('network_cell'):
   w = tf.get_variable('w', [1] )
   b = tf.get_variable('b', [1])

def give_output(inputs):

     output=[]
     cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(state_size)
     rnn_outputs, _ = tf.nn.rnn(cell, rnn_inputs, dtype = tf.float32, initial_state=init_state)

      with tf.variable_scope('network_cell', reuse=True):
               W = tf.get_variable('W', [1] )
               b = tf.get_variable('b', [1])
               output = rnn_outputs*W+b

      return output

def train_network():
    prediction= give_output(x)
    loss=tf.nn.l2_loss(prediction-y)

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

    s=tf.Session()
    init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    s.run(init)

    _, loss_value=s.run([optimizer,loss], feed_dict={x:x_data,y: y_data})

     return loss_value
```

I am calling this script from a different script called `run.py` to collect the `loss_value` for several runs:

```
 from fit import *
 loss_values=np.zeros(10)
 for i in range(10):
       loss_values(i)= train_network()
       print("Successfully done",i)
```

However I am receiving this following error after I called the script once:

```
 Successfully done 0
 Valueerror: Variable/RNN/BasicRNNCell/Linear/Matrix already exists, disallowed.
 Did you men to set reuse=True in VarScope?
```

I think the issue is because it's using the same graph as in iteration `0` even for iteration `1`. How do I make sure that the entire script `fit.py` is called afresh each time I call `train_network`?

Comment: If you actually want a separate model each time (with variables initialized from scratch), you can either construct a new `graph = tf.Graph()` each time (and set it as the default graph with `with graph.as_default():`), or just `tf.reset_default_graph()`. If you don't want to throw away all training done up to that point, you may just want to call `s.run` in a loop feeding different data each time.

Comment: @AllenLavoie: With `s.run` running in a loop, the basic graph structure would be the same but the initializaiton of variables, optimization is done from scratch again right?

Comment: Variables persist across graph executions, so their values only get reset if you explicitly re-run the `global_variables_initializer()` op. All of the values and gradients which rely on variables are computed from scratch each `run` call, so keeping exactly the same graph but feeding different data is the recommended way to train (since graph construction has some overhead, and expanding the graph on each iteration is very problematic).

Comment: @AllenLavoie: In other words, it suffices to run the last four lines of the above code starting from `s=tf.Session()` in some loop as long as number of runs right?

Comment: You can even keep the same session. Still not sure why you want to reset variables that many times, but yes it should do what you're asking.

Comment: @AllenLavoie: I just want to compute the average loss value over many runs so thats why I am rerunning the same network from scratch every time. Let me know if there is a better way to do the same task as people in ML usually do.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's a reasonable thing to do. Usually training just takes too long for that to be feasible, I guess.

Comment: I tried doing this but it looks like every iteration, the model gets worse and loss keeps increasing. Any ideas?